# Browser channel throws Error parsing forward channel Error: Invalid maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, codemirror, sharejs

I'm using browser channel to create a web socket in order to use sharejs and code mirror on my site. As the client tries to live-update the db on my server im continuously getting the error "Error parsing forward channel Error: Invalid maps". What is causing this?